# Lebesgue integral to get cumulative distribution function of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, lebesgue-integral

In the following, I tried to get cdf of random variable $X$, which has an $\operatorname{Exp}(1)$ distribution, by lebesgue integral.

> **Probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$**: $\mathbb{P}$ a probability measure on $\Omega$. A random variable $X$ is a deterministic function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$. Distribution of $X$: determined by how $\mathbb{P}$ assigns probabilities to subsets $\Omega$ and how $X$ maps those to subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

> **An example:** $\Omega = [0,1]$, and $\mathbb{P}$ is uniform on $\Omega$, i.e., for $0\leq a\leq b\leq 1$: $\mathbb{P}[a,b] = b-a$.
> Define $X:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $X(w) = -\log w$. Under $\mathbb{P}$ the rv $X$ has an $\operatorname{Exp}(1)$ distribution.

First, I partitioned y-axis: $[e^{-\frac{i}{n}},e^{-\frac{i-1}{n}}]$
So the found lebesgue integral was
$$
\operatorname*{lim}_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{ix}{n}\left(e^{-((i-1)/n)\,x}-e^{-(i/n)\,x}\right)}\right) =  1 - \frac{1+x}{e^x}
$$

It should be $1-e^{-x}$ but I got wrong in somewhere.

Could you explain where i misunderstood and how to get cdf?

Comment: $P(-\log w \leq x)=P(w\geq e^{-x})=1-e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, there are more straightforward ways to do this.  Even if you want to be extra formal, you can observe that the cdf $F$ of $X$ is, by definition:
$$F(x) = P(X\leq x) = \mathbb{P}\bigl(\{\omega\in\Omega : X(\omega)\leq x\}\bigr)$$
and then just write, for $0\leq x\leq 1$:
$$\ldots 
= \mathbb{P}\bigl(\{\omega\in[0,1]:-\log(\omega)\leq x\}\bigr)
= \mathbb{P}\bigl(\{\omega\in[0,1]:\omega\geq e^{-x}\}\bigr)
= \mathbb{P}[e^{-x},1] = 1-e^{-x}
$$

In your attempt to evaluate the Lebesgue integral by summation, it looks like your limit-of-the-sum on the left-hand side corresponds to the correct integral, but the right-hand side is incorrect.